# Unable to download/install Scala sdk from intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I created a maven project in intellij and trying to download scala SDK. I'm getting the below error. Please help me if you ever encountered the same issue with the below details.

> Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
>
> :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS      module not found:
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
>   ==== local: tried
>
> C:\Users\userx.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml
>
> -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
>
> C:\Users\userx.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar
>
> ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
>
> file:/C:/Users/userx/.sbt/preloaded/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== local-preloaded: tried
>
> file:/C:/Users/userx/.sbt/preloaded/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
>
> file:/C:/Users/userx/.sbt/preloaded/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>
> ==== Maven Central: tried
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>
> ==== sbt-maven-releases: tried
>
> https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
>
> https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>
> ==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried
>
> https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
>
> https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>
> ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
>
> https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried
>
> https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
> ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
>
> ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> :::: ERRORS   Server access Error: Received fatal alert:
>   protocol_version
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> Server access Error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>   Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>
> Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>
> Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>
> Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved
>   dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found Error during
>   sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries   (see
>   C:\Users\userx.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log) Error: Could not
>   retrieve jansi 1.11

My system versions :

```
System : windows 7
IntelliJ : 2017.3.5
Maven : 3.2.2
Java : 1.7
```

Picture of how i'm trying to download :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to be behind a corporate proxy by any chance?

I was facing the same issue (behind corporate proxy and getting this same error message). I tried all the suggestions mentioned in multiple (related) threads but was able to finally resolve it by setting up the HTTP Proxy directly in IntelliJ. Here's what my settings look like (Note: specify your network username and password in the corresponding boxes):-

[image]